# JQuery Cycle Plugin: Click anywhere on page and cycle is triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm a JQuery noob and I've run into a little issue that I can't solve.
I'm using the JQuery Cycle plugin. When I preview the page, I am able to click anywhere on the page and the slideshow is triggered.

I'd like the slideshow to cycle only when the image or div is clicked.

My code is as follows:

```
$('.slideShow').cycle({ 
        fx:     'scrollUp', 
        speed:  300, 
        next:   this, 
        timeout: 0,
});
```

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="slideShow">
    <img src="images/img01.jpg"  />
    <img src="images/img02.jpg"  />
</div>
```

I've tried to wrap the JS in a click function, which doesn't work.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "next" attribute should be a jquery selector, not a javascript reference.

You should use a selector like:

```
next: ".slideShow",
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just a trick, I don't know if there's any better solution, but it should be working.

```
$('.slideShow').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollUp', 
    speed:  300, 
    next:   this, 
    timeout: 0,
});

$('.slideShow').cycle('pause');

$('.slideShow').click(function() {
    $('.slideShow').cycle('resume');
});
```

Comment: I think I'm wrong. I thought you wanted to click on the slideshow to make it start. This won't make your slideshow go to the next slide every time you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), specify `next` - the selector to use as the trigger.